# Node-Red: access XML node by attribute value

Tags: node-red

I use Node-Red to query a status list that comes back as long XML. It is basically from my Homematic home automation central unit, i.e. sensor values and status.

right now I'm querying each sensor specifically, but there is also a function to get everything at once, which looks more economically to me, as I need multiple values anyway.

However, I don't know if it is guaranteed that the values will always be at the same position.

The XML looks like this:

[image: XML provided by central unit]

In Node-Red debug window I can see the structure like this:

[image: XML in Node Red]

I know how to access each of the nodes individually, but if I use the copy Path method:

```
payload.state.device[0].channel[1].datapoint[0].$.value
```

That will eventually blow up, if the API in the central unit will change the order in the future (maybe if I add another / remove / reconnect a Sensor?)

Each Sensor has its own ID, which you can see as

```
<device name="Fenster Bad" ise_id="3416" unreach="false" config_pending="false">
```

ise_id attribute in a device node.

**Now the question:**

I'm trying to access the value highlighted in blue.
I could use different ise_ids (highlighed red) to get there.

[image: XML and highlighted what I want]

But how do I tell node Red to not go down a path by index, but rather by the attribute ise_id?

Something like:

```
payload.state.device['ise_id=3416'].channel[1].datapoint[0].$.value
```

But I can't find any thread or tutorial on the net who explicitly does exactly that...

Please find example XML here:

https://pastebin.com/ic4eDXpp

Comment: A potential solution is using a jsonata expression. It would be easier to provide you a more specific answer if you could share a XML dataset for testing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, altough i have not yet understood it ;) ... but i added some example XML here: https://pastebin.com/ic4eDXpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

[image]

The xml node will convert the XML file into a JavaScript object. The following node, that is a change node configured with a `jsonata` expression will filter only the data for the desired `ise_id`, no matter where it is in the object (or xml) structure.

You can learn more about jsonata in this link: https://docs.jsonata.org/overview

You may want to read specifically the page about `Predicate queries`: https://docs.jsonata.org/predicate

Anyway, I would be glad to clarify any question. Additionally, you can find plenty of examples of jsonata (or ask questions) in [Node-RED forum](https://discourse.nodered.org/)

Node-REd Flow:

```
[{"id":"d4dde310.a8375","type":"tab","label":"Flow 1","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"968c62d.36b67a","type":"inject","z":"d4dde310.a8375","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":160,"y":120,"wires":[["37118c19.2fd204"]]},{"id":"37118c19.2fd204","type":"file in","z":"d4dde310.a8375","name":"Read XML file","filename":"C:\\Users\\OCM\\.node-red\\static\\nrfiles\\s1.xml","format":"utf8","chunk":false,"sendError":false,"encoding":"none","x":340,"y":120,"wires":[["a493ccb.367ae3"]]},{"id":"76cd1e5e.a132f","type":"debug","z":"d4dde310.a8375","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"filter","targetType":"msg","x":780,"y":120,"wires":[]},{"id":"a493ccb.367ae3","type":"xml","z":"d4dde310.a8375","name":"","property":"payload","attr":"","chr":"","x":490,"y":120,"wires":[["70d00d31.6dd424","e7614ac8.183a78"]]},{"id":"70d00d31.6dd424","type":"change","z":"d4dde310.a8375","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"filter","pt":"msg","to":"payload.**[ise_id = '3418']","tot":"jsonata"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":630,"y":120,"wires":[["76cd1e5e.a132f"]]},{"id":"e7614ac8.183a78","type":"debug","z":"d4dde310.a8375","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","targetType":"msg","x":630,"y":200,"wires":[]}]
```

Output when filtered ise_id = '3418' (for instance):

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thanks... That is pretty simple to setup! helps a lot! Altough i'd still be interested if this is possible with XML somehow?

Comment: When working with Node-RED it is possible to do all sorts of data transformation with or without jsonata but always working with JavaScript objects (which is very close to JSON data representation). It is quite usual and safe to perform the conversion XML to Javascript objects. If this solution was helpful and fulfill your OP please consider accepting it. I wanted to remind you that there are a couple of contrib nodes specific to Homematic in Node-RED library but I never had the need of using them.